# what is expected amount of RV when having minimal sum of $U[0,1]$ RV's that must exceed 2

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let's presume that we have an experiment:
We have $sum = 0$ and we draw value from distribution $U[0, 1]$ and we add it to $sum$ and we continue to do so until $sum>2$.
Now assuming that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le 2$ and for $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i > 2$:

1. how to compute expected $n$ or even better to get distribution for
   $n$
2. how to compute $\mathbb E[X_{n+1}]$?

Comment: For a different take on your question -- consider this a renewal theory problem.  What you are calling n is really $N(t)$ and you want $E[N(t)] = M(t)$, the renewal function. (Technically you actually want  $E[N(t=2) + 1] = M(2) +1$)  The renewal equation is rarely exactly solvable, but it is solvable in the case of uniform r.v.'s.  For example see "special cases" http://www.randomservices.org/random/renewal/Equations.html  .  That 'crossing variable' $X_{n+1}$ will tend to a limiting Age and Residual life distribution (more renewal theorems).

Answer (score 0):

Let $U_n$ be a sequence of independent variables with uniform distribution over $(0,1)$, and set $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Let $\tau = \inf\{n>0: X_n>2\}$. To compute the distribution of $\tau$, we must first consider the distribution of $X_n$. For $n=2$ we can compute the density by convolution:
\begin{align}
f_U\star f_U(t) &= \int_{\mathbb R}f_U(\tau)f_U(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \int_0^t \ \mathsf d\tau \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t) + \int_{2-t}^t \ \mathsf d\tau \mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t)\\
&= t\ \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t) + (2-t)\ \mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t).
\end{align}
In general $X_n$ has the Irwin-Hall distribution, with density
$$
f_n(t) = \frac1{2(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk (-1)^k(t-k)^{n-1}\mathrm{sgn}(t-k),
$$
where $\mathrm{sgn}(\cdot)$ denotes the sign function. For $n=3$ we see that
$$
f_3(t) = \frac12 t^2\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t) + \frac12 (-2t^2+6t-3)\mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t)  + \frac12 (t-3)^2\mathsf 1_{(2,3)}(t),
$$
and so
$$
\mathbb P(\tau = 3) = \mathbb P(X_3>2) = \int_2^3 f_3(t)\ \mathsf dt = \frac16.
$$
The distribution function of $X_n$ is given by 
$$
F_n(t) = \frac1{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\binom nk(-1)^k(t-k)^n,
$$
and so for $n\geqslant 3$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\tau=n) &= \mathbb P(X_n>2)-\mathbb P(X_{n-1}>2)\\
&= 1-F_n(2)-(1-F_{n-1}(2)) = 2-(F_n(2)+F_{n-1}(2))\\
&= \frac{\left(2^{n-1}-n\right) (n-2)}{n!}.
\end{align}
The expected value of $\tau$ is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\tau] &= \sum_{n=3}^\infty n\ \mathbb P(\tau=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\left(2^{n-1}-n\right) (n-2)}{(n-1)!}\\
&= e(e-1).
\end{align}

Comment: when computing $P(\tau)$ there should be $1-F_n(2)-(1-F_{n-1}(2)) = -(F_n(2)-F_{n-1}(2))$ right?

Comment: @quester Yes, I had a typo. It is fixed now.